# How to make the inputbox show up only once

Tags: vb.net

I am finishing up a final project right now and am having some trouble with my input boxes. I am creating a math board game. Every time the player (picture box) intersects with a label an input box appears with a math question. When I run my program everything goes smoothly except for the fact that multiple input boxes will show when the player intersects with a label instead of just one. This is under a timer tick sub. I have a feeling that it is an easy fix but I cannot figure it out. How do I fix that?

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick    
    Temps += 1
    lblTimer.Text = Temps 
    Dim Réponse As Integer

 If PictureBoxJoueur.Bounds.IntersectsWith(lblCase1.Bounds) Then
        Réponse = InputBox("Qu'est ce que 4 + 7 ", "Répond a la question ci-dessous:")
        If Réponse = 11 Then
            lblScore.Text += 1
            MsgBox("Bravo!")
        Else
            lblScore.Text -= 1
            MsgBox("Mauvaise réponse!")
        End If
```

Comment: Where do you have this code? In a `Timer.Tick` event? Put it in its context.

Comment: Obvious.  First, stop the timer (should be the first line in your code). Restart it after the condition if you want to continue...

Comment: Even before that, put `Option Strict On` at the top of your code file and fix the errors

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop the timer before showing the inputbox, and then start it again afterwards:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick    
       Temps += 1
       lblTimer.Text = Temps 
       Dim Réponse As Integer

       If PictureBoxJoueur.Bounds.IntersectsWith(lblCase1.Bounds) Then
             Timer1.Enabled = False
             Réponse = InputBox("Qu'est ce que 4 + 7 ", "Répond a la question ci-dessous:")
             If Réponse = 11 Then
                lblScore.Text += 1
                MsgBox("Bravo!")
             Else
                lblScore.Text -= 1
                MsgBox("Mauvaise réponse!")
            End If
      Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the timer to continue ticking you can use a bool to signal whether you are showing the input or not. I may otherwise use a mutex to mark the input code as critical, but since you're using a Timer, that runs on the UI and we don't want to hold up the UI thread.

```vb
Option Strict On

' Namespace, Class declaration

Private Temps As Integer
Private score As Integer
Private isDoingInput As Boolean = False

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Temps += 1
    lblTimer.Text = Temps.ToString

    If isDoingInput Then Exit Sub
    isDoingInput = True
    If PictureBoxJoueur.Bounds.IntersectsWith(lblCase1.Bounds) Then
        Dim response = InputBox("Qu'est ce que 4 + 7 ", "Répond a la question ci-dessous:")
        Dim Réponse As Integer
        If Integer.TryParse(response, Réponse) Then
            If Réponse = 11 Then
                score += 1
                lblScore.Text = score.ToString()
                MsgBox("Bravo!")
            Else
                score -= 1
                lblScore.Text = score.ToString()
                MsgBox("Mauvaise réponse!")
            End If
            ResetPictureBoxJoueur()
        Else
            MsgBox("Not a valid number!")
        End If
    End If
    isDoingInput = False
End Sub

Private Sub resetPictureBoxJoueur()
    PictureBoxJoueur.Location = New Point()
End Sub
```

I also added `Option Strict On` at the top of the code so you can do proper type conversions (they are introduced into your code). This necessitated InputBox validation as well. Also when the Input is complete, the PictureBox is still on the Label so I reset it to 0,0 but you can handle that as you see fit.

You didn't show it, but this is simple code for dragging, and this makes the app somewhat more complete.

```vb
Private isDragging As Boolean = False
Private currentPosition As New Point()

Private Sub PictureBoxJoueur_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBoxJoueur.MouseDown
    isDragging = True
    currentPosition = e.Location
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBoxJoueur_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBoxJoueur.MouseUp
    isDragging = False
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBoxJoueur_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBoxJoueur.MouseMove
    If isDragging Then
        PictureBoxJoueur.Top = PictureBoxJoueur.Top + e.Y - currentPosition.Y
        PictureBoxJoueur.Left = PictureBoxJoueur.Left + e.X - currentPosition.X
    End If
End Sub
```